# SFTP j2ssh, can i connect without password or keys?

Tags: java, sftp, j2ssh

I have to connec to the server via sftp, but i will only have the user (which is an OS user), and IP, i wont have the password or direction of the keys, is there a way to connect and upload files in that way? i am ussing j2ssh.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

How would the server authenticate you then?

While I can imagine the custom SSH/SFTP server accepting any password (for example), in general what you want is not possible.

Comment: Thanks, i though so, i just wanted to make sure, i have the address to the private key now, but i have other issue, the system returns that the address is not valid i am using this:        pk.setUsername(user);
SshPrivateKeyFile file= SshPrivateKeyFile.parse(new File(password));
SshPrivateKey key= file.toPrivateKey(null); where password is the root of the key
pk.setKeyfile(password);
pk.setKey(key);, any idea the root looks like this: /opt/file/.ssh/id

Comment: @user2777991 StackOverflow is not a discussion board, but a question-and-answer site. If you have something that can be an individual question, you are welcome to post it as a separate question on SO. Posting questions in comments is not efficient as it won't be seen by most readers.